# Websocket vs WebRTC for multiple users in same channel?

Tags: websocket, web-applications, socket.io, webrtc, chat

I want to develop a little rpg game on a web application. To explain quickly, each players have a character sheet and can use skills and attacks that will deal damage to other players.

There is generally 5 players at the same time, and there is a chat functionnality in addition.

I would originally use web socket to make communication between players and server for exchange: messages, damages, or other data that need to be share in other players.

But i see there is the WebRTC too who create a peer to peer communication and exclude the passage by the server. But if I have understand, peer-to-peer is better for only two user ?

I don't understand really what is the best solution in this case and why ?

Best regards.

Answer (score 3):

WebSockets are strictly client-server, just like plain HTTP: every client communicates with the server, and all client-client communication must be mediated by the server.  WebRTC, on the other hand, allows clients to communicate directly among themselves, without going through the server.  This gives lower latency, and better privacy, since the data does not need to go through the server.

In a large group, however, every WebRTC peer will need to connect to all other peers: with *n* peers, the total number of connections *n(n-1)/2*.  For example, in a group with just 10 participants, you will need to establish 45 connections.  Given the vagaries of the Internet, the probability that none of these will fail is essentially zero, so your application will need to be able to deal with partial connectivity, which is difficult to implement and almost impossible to debug.

In practice, peer-to-peer WebRTC is a good solution for groups with three or four participants, but unworkable beyond that.

Note that WebRTC can also be used in a client-server topology, which gives lower latency than WebSockets without the complexity of peer-to-peer error handling.  Doing that requires a server-side implementation of WebRTC (my favourite is [Pion](https://github.com/pion/webrtc/)), and is probably more involved than what you are willing to deal with.

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer. So if I understand with slution as Pion, all request of client pass by server like a websocket ? I lost the rtc errors but I increase the server bandwidth ?

It seems if there is a lot of exchange between each players the rtc is a bad idea :(

Comment: Yes, with a server-side WebRTC libary you work just like with WebSockets.  The throughput ("bandwidth") won't improve, but the latency will, because with SCTP you avoid head-of-line blocking.  And you don't lose reliability if you do it right (SCTP with multiple streams and reliable mode).  But it's somewhat more tricky than WebSockets, and the technique is likely to be obsoleted by WebTransport in future browsers.

Answer (score 0):

WebSockets Might Be Better: Since you have a game where players need to updates each other about their actions, and there's a chat functionality, WebSockets might be a better choice. It's like having that moderator who keeps track of everything and makes sure everyone knows what's going on in the game.